# Segmentation fault if I try to print all the argv arguments with a loop

Tags: arrays, assembly, segmentation-fault, arm, argv

```
.global main
.type main%function

@ r4 = argc
@ r5 = current offset
@ r6 = end offset
@ r7 = array argv

main:
    mov r4,r0
    ldr r0,=message
    mov r5,#0       // initialize offset
    mov r6,#4
    mul r6,r4,r6    // calculate end offset
    mov r7,r1       // put array argv in r7
loop:
    ldr r1,[r7,r5]  // load the argv element with offset r5
    push {ip,lr}    // save lr
    bl printf
    pop {ip,lr}
    add r5,r5,#4    // go to next word
    cmp r5,r6
    bne loop        // if I haven't reached the end offset, it does another cycle
end:
    mov r0,#0       // clear exit code
    bx lr           // returns
    
message:
    .asciz "%s\n"
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out a
./a.out
Segmentation fault
```

but:

```
$ ./a.out      
./a.out
```

so apparently the problems comes when I try to access the next element of the array... really don't know why... I'm new with arm and assembly..

Comment: This is a good opportunity to learn to use your debugger.  Pay attention to the value of `r0` as you go through the loop.

Comment: Recall that functions are allowed to clobber the `r0` to `r4` registers.  It is not guaranteed that the format string stays in `r0` across the `printf` call.

Comment: ok, I got the error. I haven't pushed r0 before the printf call, so the message is lost. Btw, I don't know at all how to use gdb. I tried to type run, but it runs and nothings happens.

Comment: If you want the program to stop, you need to set a breakpoint.  `gdb ./a.out`; `break main`; `display/i $pc`; `run`; `info registers`; `ni`; `ni` should get you started.  There should be lots of gdb tutorials online, probably mostly for x86 but not much is different.  But trying to learn assembly without knowing how to use a debugger is like learning to sew blindfolded.  Practice debugging before writing another single line of code.

Comment: @NateEldredge https://hastebin.com/nubuwihoji.yaml I don't know why, but the programs waits in this state forever

Comment: Hmm, you should probably ask that as a separate question, including details about your OS, assembler and linker, how you installed them, how you're assembling and linking your code, etc.